# New React-Native Project: Build fails (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
Xcode: 11.3.1

Creating a react-native project (react-native init GetAway) and starting it with
npx react-native run-ios throws an build error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/sercan/Desktop/Arbeit/Urlaub/rescue/GetAway/ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift
(2 failures)
```

I have no clue, why it comes to an build error, to a new created project.
If you have any ideas to solve this problem, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

**Edit:** Link for full error message: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o6tj9OrWmH-OZ5rCkYxhQTi-RYH36S5u36zpmBHHY3E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

In my macOS system, this build error was resolved by restarting the computer. The issue has been reported at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28777, where I also found this workaround.

Comment: i restarted my computer but still not working

Answer (score 1):

i fixed something similar by updating my xcode to 13 which requires that you update your macos to 11

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by uninstalling the globally installed react-native-cli.
The react-native environment setup docs also state this.

[React Native Environment Setup Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

[Screenshot from the environment setup docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVdKv.png)